# Unable to connect signalR through nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm learning how to use docker-compose to deploy app.
I got a asp.net core web api which got signalR endpoint.
It works fine when I just run on host machine.
But after I run with nginx then I can't connect to it, but the api still works fine.
Any advice would be extremely grateful.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  proxy:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
  app1:
    build: ./API
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespw@127.0.0.1:5432/datingapp
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  app2:
    build: ./API
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespw@127.0.0.1:5432/datingapp
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespw
```

my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  upstream backend {
    server api1:80;
    server api2:80;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}
```

websocket error:
[image: websocket error message]

log inside nginx:
[image: nginx log]

one of the backend server log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to create a WebSocket connection from scratch, you’ll have to handle the handshaking process yourself. After creating the initial HTTP/1.1 session, you need to request the upgrade by adding to a standard request the Upgrade and Connection headers, as follows: Connection: Upgrade Upgrade: websocket

Change your `nginx.conf` file like below.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  upstream backend {
    server api1:80;
    server api2:80;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend/hubs/presence;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location /hubs/presence{
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried the config of yours. still got the same result. But seems like the server could get the request.

Comment: @Ian I have updated the answer, please kindly check it.  Useful link: [Deploy .NET Core web site wit SignalR behind Nginx reverse proxy](https://binary-notes.ru/deploy-net-core-web-site-wit-signalr-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy/)